# \usepackage{tikz} not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, texniccenter

I'm using MikTex and am trying to import the TikZ package to draw some graphics in LaTeX. When the pdf builds however it doesn't recognise the package TikZ and fails. Every other package I am using works fine. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? This could just be a dumb question like I haven't downloaded ... which you need to run it but in the online manual there doesn't seem to be any system requirements etc.

Comment: For your TeX distribution, are you using MikTeX or TeXlive or something else? Have you tried installing the PGF or PGF/TikZ package through your TeX distribution's package manager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the `pgf` package as TikZ belongs to `pgf`, it's just the frontend. If you use MiKTeX, use the MiKTeX package manager aka mpm, with TeX Live use the TeX Live Manager aka tlmgr. You may find it in the start menu.

- [MiKTeX pgf package information](http://miktex.org/packages/pgf)
- [pgf on CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)

Comment: Thanks - it was obviously something simple. I just typed mpm in the cmd line to get the package manager up.