# How to draw shape as 'curved arrows' with text (with tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes

I would like to draw the figure below with Tikz. My research on the web to draw a curved arrow with text yielded nothing.

[image: Image with curved arrows]

On the other hand, I wonder how to direct the arrow to the left with the text not upside down.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[semithick,x=20mm, y=20mm]

        \node[single arrow, draw,single arrow tip angle=100, align=center] [rotate=0] at (0,0) {Test \\ test test};
        \node[single arrow, draw,single arrow tip angle=100, align=center] [rotate=180] at (1,0) {Test \\ test test};

    \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Who can help me
1. Draw shape "curved arrows"
2. orient these arrows correctly

Answer (score 13):

I wouldn't actually actually use the arrow nodes for this, but draw very thick lines with arrowheads and add nodes afterwards. However, you need PGF 3.0.0 for fine control over the arrowhead parameters:

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  thick arrow/.style={
     -{Triangle[angle=120:1pt 1]},
     line width=1.5cm, 
     draw=gray
  },
  arrow label/.style={
    text=white,
    font=\sf,
    align=center
  },
  set mark/.style={
    insert path={
      node [midway, arrow label, node contents=#1]
    }
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [thick arrow]
  (-6,0) -- (-3,0) [set mark={Processues \\ de d\'emarrage}];

\draw [thick arrow]
   (-2,0) -- (-2,1.5)
   arc (180:0:2 and 1.5) [set mark={Processus \\ de planification}]
   -- (2,0.5);

\draw [thick arrow]
   (2,0) -- (2,-1.5) 
   arc (360:180:2 and 1.5) [set mark={Processus \\ d'ex\'ecution}]
   -- (-2,-0.5);

\draw [thick arrow]
  (3,0) -- (6,0) [set mark={Processues \\ de cl\^oture}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution is simple and very attractive. Thank you! Nevertheless I seek adequate mirror that contains the "pgf3" package or the library "arrows.meta" that MiKTeX Package Manager does not find...

Comment: Ok pgf 3 found  on http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/ and info on this post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25994/usepackagetikz-not-working ...