# How to align a "double arrow" with a tikz arc shape?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to align the `double arrow` shape in the `tikz` package with an arc, like this one:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[a2paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,shapes.arrows,shadows,arrows,positioning,shapes}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,node distance=1cm, auto,baseline=-.5ex]

\node (dummy) at (-5,-8) {}; 

\begin{scope}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(dummy.center)}]
\draw (8.75,4.75) arc (440:160:7.5); % I'm trying to align my double arrow shape with this arc.
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

By popular demand - a picture: [image: picture]

Preferrably I want the arrow tips to be unaffected by the bending of the shape. This would probably require a different shape than `double arrow`, though.

Comment: Could you please describe it a little more? If you could add a drawing by hand, it would be great, because there is no double arrow, it is difficult to imagine what you are trying to achive.

Comment: One tip: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153922/how-to-draw-shape-as-curved-arrows-with-text-with-tikz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Workaround (version 1)

I have only a workaround for you. I draw two arrows on each other, the arrowheads are shifted, so I manually move them slightly back. The first arrowhead's position is controlled by an extra point, the second arrowhead's position is controlled by an angle and a distance. Please try it if it fits your needs.

```
%! *latex mal-doublearrow.tex
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[a2paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
%\usetikzlibrary{fadings,shadows,arrows,positioning,shapes}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{mal/.style={<->, >=stealth, 
double arrow, line width=8mm,
 draw=black, double arrow head extend=1.5cm, double arrow head indent=1.25cm}}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=2,node distance=1cm, auto,baseline=-.5ex]
\node (dummy) at (-5,15) {}; 
\begin{scope}[remember picture,overlay,at={(dummy)}]
\def\malpath{(7,5)-- (8.75,4.75) arc (440:160:7.5)--+(65:2)}
\draw[mal] \malpath; % I'm trying to align my double arrow shape with this arc.
\def\malpath{(7.2,5)--(8.75,4.75) arc (440:160:7.5)--+(65:1.8)}
\draw[mal, line width=6mm, draw=yellow] \malpath;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

---

> Edit (version 2)

```
%! *latex mal-doublearrow.tex
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[a2paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{mal/.style={<->, >={Stealth[length=40mm,sep=-5mm]},
 double distance=6mm, line width=5mm,
 draw=black, double=yellow}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\draw[mal](6.5,5)--(8.75,4.75) arc (440:160:7.5)--+(70:2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Does this workaround offer any options to color the arrow similarly to the regular "flat" `double arrow`? My next step is to make the shape gradually fade in color, with say: `[left color=blue,right color=green,middle color=cyan]`

Comment: It would require some more experiments. I am using `line width`, it can be changed, the yellow can be changed to `white` as well as to a shading object (untested). Your turn. `:-)`

Comment: I think I have an idea about using tikzfading and the `draw={fading}` command. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: You can redefine mal style or copy its content directly to the `\node`s. I think that I have made some mistake anyway as `double arrow head *` parameters seem not to work. Yes, I am, you asked for it (in drawing). I believe there is some `double line width` parameter and that second arrow won't be needed.

Comment: Oh, `double distance=4mm`, `double=yellow` it is... It looks there is more work in it.

Comment: I polished the first version, but no, shading is not working if we would like to change the yellow color, it is filling the inner part of a circle.

Comment: Is there no way for the parser to "scan" the current objects drawn in the PDF and then assign them to a node? That way we could circumvent the necessity of this fade-type color functionality within PGF/tikz, as I believe tikz may not offer it.

Comment: That `tikzfading` library sounds like a good idea, otherwise we try to mix up `\node` and `\draw` commands.

Comment: One more tip (a nonlinear transformation): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166860/how-to-bend-a-tikz-node/167109

Comment: I've already seen that one. The problem is that my picture is huge and these nonlinear transformations are impractical to use because everything scales (which was also a remark by the poster of the answer). I honestly don't see a way my specific idea can be implemented: **I** If I try to use this last answer, I'm working for hours on getting the right set of coordinates for my bezier. I can't get it right at such enormous distances. **II** If I use your answer and transform the `mal` into a `node`, I get similar problematic results. I'm starting to think that tikz simply can't do this.

Comment: You could draw the contour all by yourself. I have done that once using `to` and several `in`s and `out`s.

Comment: I will try to find my old code for that arrow drawn from a scratch. I am not promising a thing, but I will try.

Comment: Try it, it might be it, but it is hard to guess.

Comment: Whoever might find it useful, [this thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171192/how-to-use-i-e-left-middle-and-right-color-when-using-draw-as-an-argument-inst) has the intended functionality MINUS the ability to place the object on a particular place in the picture.