# Tikz large curved arrow, filled with border

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows

I find out many topics on this forum concerning curved arrows,

- [How to draw shape as 'curved arrows' with text (with tikz)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153922/how-to-draw-shape-as-curved-arrows-with-text-with-tikz)
- [Curved text (on multiple lines) within curved arrow using tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75432/curved-text-on-multiple-lines-within-curved-arrow-using-tikz)
- [Create curved TikZ single arrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95936/create-curved-tikz-single-arrow)

however I am not able to find among them a simple and working solution for producing folowing arrow shape:

[image]

I try using following code but it does not deliver the expected result. Could someone explain me why my approach is not showing the border in black and why the tip of the arrow is not displayed.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=10px]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[single arrow, draw=black, fill=gray, -stealth, line width=1pt](0,0) arc(45:-140:.5) (1.25,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What you are doing is to produce an arc and then moving the pen to the position `(1.25,2)`. To draw the arrow you need to change the end point. For example, just use `(0,0) arc(45:-140:.5)` but the result is not what you want.

Answer (score 7):

A solution not using the library but made by hand.

```
\documentclass[margin=10px]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=gray,line width=1pt] (0:1cm) arc (0:-180:1cm) -- (-180:1.25cm) -- (-.75,.75) -- (-180:.25cm) -- (-180:.5cm) arc (-180:0:.5cm)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[rotate=45,fill=gray,line width=1pt] (0:1cm) arc (0:-180:1cm) -- (-180:1.25cm) -- (-.75,.75) -- (-180:.25cm) -- (-180:.5cm) arc (-180:0:.5cm)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe, using `(-.75,.5)` instead of `(-.75,.75)` could produce a better result.

[image]

Comment: Your proposal works fine, i find out that I can reduce the size by the use of scale=0.5. But how can use your code line with relative coordonate. Something like at \node (x,y) \draw ... Thanks in advance

Comment: @ChrisDE You could make it into a `pic`, perhaps?

Comment: @ cfr, thanks for the response. I am using this special arrow in a tikzpicture environment with other draw and node elements. Usually, it is possible for any draw element to set it position by the definition of coordinate. I do not manage to make the given code work without changing all dimensions in the case of other positioning.