# Add double arrow with some text on real line of numbers

Tags: tikz-arrows

Que: See the attached figure how can I achieve it? I want to draw arrows on both sides of the real lines with some text inside it.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=0.2in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,intersections}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.5]
        \draw[thick,latex-latex] (-5,0) -- (6,0)node[right]{};
        \foreach \x in {-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}{
            \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.20pt,label=below:$\x$] at (\x,0) {};
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look at this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153922/how-to-draw-shape-as-curved-arrows-with-text-with-tikz

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it, by changing the shape of a node. See the comments in the code. See chapters 71.5 and 17.2.3 in the tikzmanual.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=0.2in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}
% ~~~ commented out all that's not needed here ~~~~~~~~~
%\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
%\usepackage{latexsym}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{newlfont}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
%\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
%\usepackage{xparse}
%\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,intersections}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        xscale=1.5,
        dots/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1.20pt},
    ]
        \draw[thick,latex-latex] (-5,0) -- (6,0)node[right]{};
%        \foreach \x in {-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}{% can be shortened
        \foreach \x in {-4,-3,...,4}{
            \node[dots,label=below:$\x$] at (\x,0) {};
        };
        
        % ~~~ arrows ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \node[  single arrow,       % node shaped like an arrow
                anchor=west,        % i.e. the postion below
                fill=green!40,draw=blue
            ] 
                at (0.3,1) {Some text};
                
        \node[  single arrow,
                anchor=east,
                fill=red!40,draw=purple,
                shape border rotate=180,    % rotates shape, not text
              ] 
                at (-0.3,1) {Some more text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**P.S.** For colored dots just split the loop and do:

```
        \foreach \x in {-4,-3,-2,-1}{
            \node[dots,,fill=red,label=below:$\x$] at (\x,0) {};
        };
        \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4}{
            \node[dots,fill=green,label=below:$\x$] at (\x,0) {};
        };
```

[image: colored]

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. One small doubt how to increase length of arrow. I mean how to control thickness and length.

Comment: One more question how can I give red colors to all negative numbers, green to all positive numbers and yellow to zero.

Comment: For the colored dots see "P.S". // Because the arrows are just the shape of nodes, AND nodes adjust their size according to their textual content, to a large degree length is no problem. If you want to do more, kindly read about the parameter options here https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#sec-71.5 and here https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.2 . // You may also use a \makebox inside the node, like: `\node at (-0.3,1) {\makebox[7cm]{Some more text}};` , where the width of the box resizes the node. See e.g. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#makebox_and_mbox .

Comment: For valuable suggestions and corrections, thank you so much. Along with dots is it possible to give colors to numbers. I think zero is missing on number line

Comment: Fine. Yes to both. You‘ll find both answers in the manual, like how to place a third colored node, and how to impact its text color. We try to help, not to free from joy or burden of learning.

Comment: Agree with you. Kindly share the pdf file link of manual. I will go through and try to achieve whatever I want for this question

Comment: Just see my first comment, or try your search engine on packages like tikz ;-)

Comment: Can you modify codes for above said question?

Comment: Yes, I can. No, I won't, it's not that difficult. BTW, I get this warning while typing: **Please avoid extended discussions in comments.**